# Persist selected month in all dropdown toggle div's angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm displaying data under toggle option wherin I'm keeping open the clicked card.But if I click other month all other greyed headers are having the previously selected values.

I'm finding a way to persist the value under `Selected month` to be the way it was actually selected.
**Eg:** :For the first time I selected value under card `2017` as `Apr 1` ,the drop down toggle div displays as `Selected month :Apr`.

Now navigate to card `2018` and click on `Oct 18` the value in both the opened drop downs turns out to be `Selected month: Oct` which is changing the previously selected month as well.Is there any way to persist/display the previously selected month.

Plunker link (pls preview output in windowed mode):[Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/6nkflGCUw0XYFkl2ayge?p=preview)

Comment: What about this https://plnkr.co/edit/MfXci24ErPxdHEl1Au3e?p=preview

Comment: @yogendarji it worked thanks!.can you pls answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than single variable `this.selectedMonth`, Use `yearData.selectedMonth` with each year data.

[updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfXci24ErPxdHEl1Au3e?p=preview)

> HTML set with {{yearData.selected}}

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="isActive[i1]">
        <div class="grey-header">
            Selected month:{{yearData.selected}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JS changes

Add `selected` key in your osData.

Now on each row click, set `this.osData[i].selected = month;`

```
 this.osData=  [{"cardData":[{"view":"Jan","count":1},{"view":"Apr","count":1},{"view":"Jun","count":1}],"selected:": "", "year":2017,"month":"June","family":"AND"},{"cardData":[{"view":"Jan","count":25},{"view":"Oct","count":18},{"view":"Nov","count":14},{"view":"Dec","count":18}],"selected:": "","year":2018,"month":"June","family":"NOU"},{"cardData":[{"view":"Jan","count":21},{"view":"Feb","count":11},{"view":"Mar","count":22},{"view":"Apr","count":18},{"view":"Nov","count":11},{"view":"Dec","count":16}],"selected:": "","year":2019,"month":"June","family":"HNY"},{"cardData":[{"view":"Jan","count":10},{"view":"Jun","count":9},{"view":"Nov","count":5},{"view":"Dec","count":8}],"selected:": "","year":2020,"month":"June","family":"GIN"}]
     this.setClickedMonth = function (index, i,month) {
            this.selectedMonthIndex = index;
            this.osData[i].selected = month;
            this.selectedMonth=month;
            if (this.isActive[i] === false) {
                this.isActive[i] = !this.isActive[i];
                this.selectedMonthIndex = '';
            } else {
                this.isActive[i] = !this.isActive[i];
            }
         }

   }
```